# What is happening when we submit jar to storm cluster?

Tags: apache-storm

How Nimbus-Zookeeper-Supervisor-Workers will work after we run 'storm jar' command? What are the processes will happen at background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The life cycle of a storm topology includes a lot of steps behind the scene. 
[Check this link](https://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Lifecycle-of-a-topology.html) for a very details explanation of what exactly happening once you run the storm jar command. 
Unfortunately the link above refers back to a old version of storm and I couldn't find any updated doc, but this should give you a much clear idea about the same.